# Merging keyframes from separate actions for 2 armatures with API

Tags: python, keyframes, actions

I'm honestly out of ideas with this one.
Basically I have 2 armatures, each one of them has it's own action.
In the end I want to still have those 2 armatures separated but only one action to drive both of them. I technically know how to do it via interface using some copy-paste shenanigans, but how can I access the full data set to duplicate it and place it in one of the actions along existing data?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of poking and prodding but i figured it out.
Once I found out where the data resides I managed to pull it into array, sort it into usable multi-dimensional table and inject data to other actions.

```
bpy.data.actions[].fcurves.keyframe_points.co # [keyframe_nr, value]
bpy.data.actions[].fcurves.data_path #RNA path to property
bpy.data.actions[].fcurves.array_index #RNA index
```